# How do I get the bubble sort swap to work correctly?

Tags: c, sorting, for-loop, bubble-sort

```
int i, j, temp, sort[5] = {5, 3, 6, 43, 11};

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if(sort[j] < sort[i]) {
            temp = sort[i];      
            sort[i] = sort[j];   
            sort[j] = temp;   
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make a bubble sort and I tried to initialize a 'small' variable in the outer for loop to set it as the smallest integer. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show? Can you please try to make it into a [mre]? And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Tip: Declare your values in as narrow a scope as possible, like in this case `for (int i = 0; ...)` This helps keep your code clean and more easily understood.

Comment: This is an ideal chance to learn about using a debugger and stepping through your code to see what's wrong.

Comment: Note: Why are you comparing 0 with 0? Hint: `for (int j = i + 1; ...)`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if(sort[j] < sort[i])
> ```

this **if** condition is logically wrong that's why swap is not working, instead it should be

> ```
> if(sort[j] > sort[j+1])
> ```

Moreover there is no need to run the outer loop 5 times. **4** is enough because , all the elements become sorted at **n-1** iterations.
Similarly the inner loop can be iterated **n-i-1** times instead of **i** as the elements towards the end become sorted

Finally the corrected code is

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  for(j = 0; j < i-1; j++) {
    if(sort[j] > sort[j+1]) {
        temp = sort[i];      
        sort[i] = sort[j];   
        sort[j] = temp;   
     }
   }
 }
```